# Tidy several variables with different keys at once in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have some trouble tidying my data. I have a table with 10 peptide sequences and I have recorded their abundance mean, standard deviation and coeficient of variance across three samples: Reference, ZAP02 and ZAP02_GA.

The initial table is a 10x10

```
example <- data.frame(
Sequence = c("YVVDTSK","EALDFFAR","VLGIDGGEGKEELFR","VLGIDGGEGK","DIPVPKPK","IGDYAGIK",       "DWVQAVR","DNIEPILK","LLDGTVVSR","NQETSEEYQIK"),
Reference = c(1098144.12,  41276.04,  172023.14,  399734.69, 1242669.19, 1585792.75, 1676065.88, 2152511.00, 60473.17,  768250.31),
Reference_SD = c(48098.6407,    888.9603,   8572.5207,   2475.0947,  92398.6154, 287270.7919,  71968.6762, 73495.9717,   5610.4587,  52914.2146),
Reference_CV = c( 4.3799934,  2.1536957,  4.9833532, 0.6191844,  7.4354958, 18.1152797,  4.2939050,  3.4144296,  9.2776003,  6.8876268),
ZAP02_GA = c(  NaN,      NaN, 1788.838,      NaN, 1298.561,      NaN,      NaN, 1926.935,      NaN,      NaN),
ZAP02_GA_SD = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
ZAP02_GA_CV = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
ZAP02 = c( NaN,       NaN,  2286.836,      NaN, 12303.839,       NaN,  2535.902,  2806.022,       NaN,       NaN),
ZAP02_SD = c( NA,        NA, 1393.2599,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,  218.3964,        NA,        NA),
ZAP02_CV = c(NA,        NA, 60.925235,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,  7.783131,        NA,        NA))
```

I would like to tidy my data to have one column for the means, another for the SD values and another for the CV. At the end, I should have a table with 30 rows and 5 variables (Sequence, Sample, Abundance, Standard Deviation and CV).

I tried to use the `gather()` function for this purpose, but at the end I got a very long and confusing dataframe.

```
example_tidy <- example %>%
  gather(Reference, ZAP02_GA, ZAP02,
         key = "Sample",
         value = "Abundance") %>%
  gather(Reference_SD, ZAP02_GA_SD, ZAP02_SD,
         key = "Sample",
         value = "Standard deviation") %>%
  gather(Reference_CV, ZAP02_GA_CV, ZAP02_CV,
         key = "Sample",
         value = "CV (%)")
```

To get what I want, I had to gather the means, sd and cv in separate dataframes and then column bind them. But this turn out tedious and time consuming.

```
example_mean <- example %>%
  gather(Reference, ZAP02_GA, ZAP02,
         key = "Sample",
         value = "Abundance")

example_sd <- example %>%
  gather(Reference_SD, ZAP02_GA_SD, ZAP02_SD,
         key = "Sample",
         value = "Standard deviation")

example_cv <- example %>%
  gather(Reference_CV, ZAP02_GA_CV, ZAP02_CV,
         key = "Sample",
         value = "CV (%)")

example_tidy2 <- cbind(select(example_mean, Sequence, Sample, Abundance),
                       "Standard deviation" = example_sd$`Standard deviation`,
                       "CV (%)" = example_cv$`CV (%)`)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Can you do a `gather()` with several keys?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: In your `example_tidy2` you get some rows with no values (e.g. YFFDTSK NaN abundance...). Do you want such rows?

Comment: Note that `gather` is a retired function, so you should be looking for answers with `pivot_longer` instead

Comment: Yes please, I would like to keep everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case `pivot_longer()` can treat.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

example %>%
  rename_at(vars(-matches("Seq|SD|CV")), paste0, "_Abundance") %>%
  pivot_longer(-Sequence, names_to = c("Sample", ".value"), names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)")

# # A tibble: 30 x 5
#    Sequence        Sample    Abundance     SD     CV
#    <fct>           <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 YVVDTSK         Reference  1098144. 48099.  4.38 
#  2 YVVDTSK         ZAP02_GA       NaN     NA  NA    
#  3 YVVDTSK         ZAP02          NaN     NA  NA    
#  4 EALDFFAR        Reference    41276.   889.  2.15 
#  5 EALDFFAR        ZAP02_GA       NaN     NA  NA    
#  6 EALDFFAR        ZAP02          NaN     NA  NA    
#  7 VLGIDGGEGKEELFR Reference   172023.  8573.  4.98 
#  8 VLGIDGGEGKEELFR ZAP02_GA      1789.    NA  NA    
#  9 VLGIDGGEGKEELFR ZAP02         2287.  1393. 60.9  
# 10 VLGIDGGEGK      Reference   399735.  2475.  0.619
# … with 20 more rows
```

---

1. The term `.value` has special meaning in `pivot_longer()`. You can search `?pivot_longer` for more details and practice its examples part.
2. Parentheses divide a string into multiple groups. The structure of `names_pattern` corresponds to the elements of `names_to`. Take `ZAP02_SD` for example. The first `(.*)` extracts `ZAP02` and puts it into the `Sample` column. The second `(.*)` extracts `SD` and defines it as a new column, which is what `.value` works for.
3. The information about pattern matching can be found by searching ***"Regular expression"*** or ***"Regex"*** on google. [Wikipedia of regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is a good resource for beginners. All the special symbols I use in my answer like `"|"`, `"("`, `"."`, `"*"` are recorded and explained in it.

Comment: That was so simple to do!! Thank you Darren!
Three questions though:
Why do you write ".value" instead of "value"?
Why do you use parentheses for the name pattern, and not write ".*_.*"?
Do you know of a cheat sheet for string recognition for grepl and similar? Like .*  \\s etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired outputs without splitting each variable in a new dataframe, but I think there still needs to be an intermediary step involved - although my solution might not be the most elegant.

If your sample/variable names were more consistent, I would have used `separate` after the first `gather` to split e.g. Reference_CV into a Sample (Reference) and Measure (CV) column, but because means were not named and you have sample names containing underscores, I used regular expressions to select them.

First step gathers all the values (regardless what type of values they are) into one value column.

```
step1 <- gather(example, key = "Sample", value = "value", 2:10)
```

Then I create a "measure" column that gets filled based on information pulled from the sample name, and tidy up the "Sample" column to remove that information. (Here is where someone could chip in with a more elegant and widely applicable solution, but that's all I could come up with based on your naming conventions.)

```
step1 <- step1 %>% mutate(
   measure = case_when(
      grepl("_CV", Sample) ~ "CV",
      grepl("_SD", Sample) ~ "SD",
      !grepl("_CV", Sample) & !grepl("_SD", Sample) ~ "Abundance"
   ),
   Sample = case_when(
      grepl("Reference", Sample) ~ "Reference",
      grepl("ZAP02_GA", Sample) ~ "ZAP02_GA",
      grepl("ZAP02", Sample) ~ "ZAP02"
   )
)
```

And finally I spread the resulting data frame to put the measures back into their own columns: Abundance, CV and SD.

```
output <- spread(step1, key = measure, value = value)
dim(output)
[1] 30  5
```

You can condense all of this in one long pipe, but I thought it would be easier to demonstrate the steps like this. Hope that helps!

Comment: You're welcome but take a look at Darren's answer below, which is a lot more compact. I need to make the switch to the pivot functions too!